# TeamViewer API and PostMan

Tags: python, api, teamviewer

I'm searching for a way to parse multiple API requests using a postman snippet in python.

The following works:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("webapi.teamviewer.com")

payload = "remotecontrol_id=rxxxxxxxx&groupid=g18932019&alias=test1%20api&password=xxxxxx"

headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/api/v1/devices", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

How can I do this with multiple payloads.?

Comment: Where is your data (ids and passwords) stored?

Comment: Your edit to my answer was not correct, you removed intendation that is crucial in python. I added it back and fixed the error, it should work now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("webapi.teamviewer.com")

headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

ids = [35123241, 234234234, 1232312, 5644352, 234243234]
pws = ["47gj6", "fgdg6as", "saa23d", "a24asd", "gre42as"]

for i in range(len(ids)):
    payload = "remotecontrol_id=r%s&groupid=g18932019&alias=%s&password=%s" % (ids[i], ids[i], pws[i])

    conn.request("POST", "/api/v1/devices", payload, headers)

    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()

    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

You just need to initialize/populate `ids` and `pws` with your actual data somehow and they need to be of same size obviously (passwords on `pws` belong to the ids in `ids` at the same position).